# Unity build app for both tvOS and iOS in a single Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, tvos

We want to deploy our game to both the Apple TV on tvOS as well as the iPhone and iPad on iOS. When building the app separately in Unity for either tvOS or iOS, everything works fine. However, Unity does not support creating an Xcode project which contains both build targets - which is required for the app to appear as a single app in the App Store.

I know this has been done multiple times before since most Apple Arcade games are built in Unity and all support both tvOS and iOS. We've tried making a tvOS build and adding the iOS build target manually, but even after resolving many errors, we're still not able to run the app as it crashes immediately.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?